# Collapse Bootstrap на чистом JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Помогите верстать это место. В Bootstrap'е оно называется *Collapse*. Я хочу сделать чисто на HTML, JQuery:

[image: Изображение для верстки]

Comment: https://google.gik-team.com/?q=%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD+css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. ***Самый лёгкий accordion с минимальным использованием JQuery.*** Для анимации нужно в CSS добавить transition и указывать фиксированную высоту для пунктов:

   ```js
   $(function() {
     $('.accordion-item-title').click(function() {
       var $item = $(this).parents('.accordion-item');
       
       $item.toggleClass('accordion-item--active').siblings('.accordion-item--active').removeClass('accordion-item--active');
     });
   });
   ```

   ```css
   body {font-family: arial;}

   .body {
       width: 80%;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .title {
       padding: 20px 0;
   }

   .title-text {
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 32px;
       font-weight: 700;
       color: black;
   }
   .title-line {
       width: 65px;
       height: 4px;
       margin: 15px 0;
       background-color: black;
   }

   .accordion {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
   }

   .accordion-item {
       height: 45px;
       margin: 5px 0;
       border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   .accordion-item.accordion-item--active {height: auto;}

   .accordion-item-title {
       padding: 12px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: 700;
       color: black;
       cursor: pointer;
   }
   .accordion-item--active .accordion-item-title {
       color: #57d4e5;
   }

   .accordion-item-content {
       padding: 12px;
       color: #707070;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

   <div class="body">
     <div class="title">
       <div class="title-text">Our mission</div>
       <div class="title-line"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="accordion">
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">We build your dream</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Connecting people</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Make the world more beautiful</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Nithing to fear</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   С фиксированной высотой и анимацией:

   ```js
   $(function() {
     $('.accordion-item-title').click(function() {
       var $item = $(this).parents('.accordion-item');
       
       $item.toggleClass('accordion-item--active').siblings('.accordion-item--active').removeClass('accordion-item--active');
     });
   });
   ```

   ```css
   body {font-family: arial;}

   .body {
       width: 80%;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .title {
       padding: 20px 0;
   }

   .title-text {
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 32px;
       font-weight: 700;
       color: black;
   }
   .title-line {
       width: 65px;
       height: 4px;
       margin: 15px 0;
       background-color: black;
   }

   .accordion {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
   }

   .accordion-item {
       height: 45px;
       margin: 5px 0;
       border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
       overflow: hidden;
       transition: height 0.3s linear;
   }
   .accordion-item.accordion-item--active {height: 100px;}

   .accordion-item-title {
       padding: 12px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: 700;
       color: black;
       cursor: pointer;
       transition: color 0.3s linear;
   }
   .accordion-item--active .accordion-item-title {
       color: #57d4e5;
   }

   .accordion-item-content {
       padding: 12px;
       color: #707070;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

   <div class="body">
     <div class="title">
       <div class="title-text">Our mission</div>
       <div class="title-line"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="accordion">
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">We build your dream</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Connecting people</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Make the world more beautiful</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Nithing to fear</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

---

2. ***Вариант с анимацией JQuery.*** Мы по началу записываем в свойство пункта аккордеона его настоящую высоту и присваиваем ему новую - 45px. Далее при нажатии анимацией из 45px изменяем на его настоящую высоту. Анимационная смена цвета заголовка - это уже побочная анимация и её мы записываем в CSS:

   ```js
   $(function() {
     $('.accordion-item').each(function() {
       var $self = $(this),
           _height = $self.outerHeight();
     
       $self.prop('_height', _height).css('height', 45);
     });
     
     $('.accordion-item-title').click(function() {
       var $item = $(this).parents('.accordion-item'),
           $item_height = $item.prop('_height');
       
       if( !$item.hasClass('accordion-item--active') ){
         $item.animate({'height': $item_height}, 300)
              .addClass('accordion-item--active')
              .siblings('.accordion-item--active')
              .animate({'height': 45}, 300)
              .removeClass('accordion-item--active');
       }else{
         $item.animate({'height': 45}, 300)
              .removeClass('accordion-item--active');
       };
     });
   });
   ```

   ```css
   body {font-family: arial;}

   .body {
       width: 80%;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .title {
       padding: 20px 0;
   }

   .title-text {
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 32px;
       font-weight: 700;
       color: black;
   }
   .title-line {
       width: 65px;
       height: 4px;
       margin: 15px 0;
       background-color: black;
   }

   .accordion {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
   }

   .accordion-item {
       margin: 5px 0;
       border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
       overflow: hidden;
   }

   .accordion-item-title {
       padding: 12px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: 700;
       color: black;
       cursor: pointer;
       transition: color 0.3s linear;
   }
   .accordion-item--active .accordion-item-title {
       color: #57d4e5;
   }

   .accordion-item-content {
       padding: 12px;
       color: #707070;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>

   <div class="body">
     <div class="title">
       <div class="title-text">Our mission</div>
       <div class="title-line"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="accordion">
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">We build your dream</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Connecting people</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Make the world more beautiful</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
       <div class="accordion-item">
         <div class="accordion-item-title">Nithing to fear</div>
         <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

---

3. ***Ещё есть вариант с использованием [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/):***

   ```js
   $(function() {
     $('.accordion').accordion();
   });
   ```

   ```css
   body {font-family: arial;}

   .body {
       width: 80%;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .title {
       padding: 20px 0;
   }

   .title-text {
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 32px;
       font-weight: 700;
       color: black;
   }
   .title-line {
       width: 65px;
       height: 4px;
       margin: 15px 0;
       background-color: black;
   }

   .accordion {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
   }

   .accordion-item-title {
       margin: 10px 0 0;
       padding: 12px;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: 700;
       color: black;
       border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
       cursor: pointer;
       transition: color 0.3s linear;
       outline: none;
   }
   .accordion-item-title.ui-state-active {
       color: #57d4e5;
       border-bottom: 0;
   }

   .accordion-item-content {
       padding: 12px;
       color: #707070;
       border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
       border-top: 0;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   <div class="body">
     <div class="title">
       <div class="title-text">Our mission</div>
       <div class="title-line"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="accordion">
       <h3 class="accordion-item-title">We build your dream</h3>
       <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       <h3 class="accordion-item-title">Connecting people</h3>
       <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       <h3 class="accordion-item-title">Make the world more beautiful</h3>
       <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
       <h3 class="accordion-item-title">Nithing to fear</h3>
       <div class="accordion-item-content">Content text</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Спасибо большое очень благодарен!!!

Comment: @ArmanGhazaryan, не за что :)

Comment: Вы очень помогли!!!