# Как заставить javascript открыть 2-ой accordion?

Tags: javascript, css

Доброй день.

Есть код аккордеона:

```js
$(function() {
  var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    this.multiple = multiple || false;

    // Variables privadas
    var links = this.el.find('.link');
    // Evento
    links.on('click', {
      el: this.el,
      multiple: this.multiple
    }, this.dropdown)
  }

  Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
    var $el = e.data.el;
    $this = $(this),
      $next = $this.next();

    $next.slideToggle();
    $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

    if (!e.data.multiple) {
      $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
    };
  }

  var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/** =======================
 * Contenedor Principal
 ===========================*/

.accordion {
  background: #f9fBfC;
  min-height: 272px;
  margin-top: 31px;
  width: 215px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.accordion .link {
  max-height: 390px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -18px;
  padding: 28px 12px 9px;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #b9b9e5;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion li:last-child .link {
  border-bottom: 10;
}

.accordion li i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: -12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
  right: 12px;
  left: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.accordion li.open .link {
  color: #352a00;
}

.accordion li.open i {
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.accordion li.open i.fa-chevron-down {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  max-height: 290px;
}

.accordion li.default .submenu {
  display: block;
}


/**
 * Submenu
 -----------------------------*/

.submenu {
  max-height: 290px;
  display: none;
  background: ;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.submenu a {
  max-height: 290px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #010523; //цвет текста 
  font-family: bold;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 62px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #75788c;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>Trust rating<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu tab-content" id="Trust_rating">
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Raise_rating" href="#">Raise rating</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Talk_about_you" href="#">Talk about you</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Offers_to_join" href="#">Offers to join</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Activity<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu tab-content">
      <li id="main_list_item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#All1" href="#">All</a></li>
      <li id="main_list_item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Contacts1" href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>Result<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu tab-content">
      <li id="main_list_item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#All2" href="#">All</a></li>
      <li id="main_list_item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Contacts2" href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Social networks<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
    <ul class="submenu tab-content">
      <li id="main_list_item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="Name_sotial_network" href="#"> Name sotial network</a></li>
      <li id="main_list_item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="Name_sotial_network" href="#"> Name sotial network</a></li>
      <li id="main_list_item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="Name_sotial_network" href="#"> Name sotial network</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Я сделал 2-ой такой же Accordion с теми же свойствами, но он не работает (не раскрывается). Видимо дело все в JavaScript. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Пояснения работы кода - [Как звучит данный сценарий аккордеона?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482996/)

Comment: Просто для информации - Вы при открытии вопроса не видели какую совершенно не читаемую кашу вставили?

Comment: Ошибки значит надо смотреть.... ибо всё воспроизводится.......или дело в multiple = false

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!Это был мой первый раз когда я писал вопрос здесь.Поэтому так нехорошо получилось.Ивиняюсь. А как избавиться от multiple? Спасибо

Comment: Откатить читаемый вопрос обратно во тьму безграмотности?

Comment: @Other, лучше решите вопрос :) Мне кажется это будет полезнее откатов

Comment: Стараюсь! Пока что не выходит!

Comment: @IgorKoryakin, у меня раскрывается, но закрывает пункты во втором :)

Comment: @IgorKoryakin, можете воспользоваться [моими реализациями Accordion'а](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640953/collapse-bootstrap-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-jquery/640973#640973). Они будут полегче чем это :)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!